# Incorrect Display Resolution

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution

I have been trying to fix my monitor resolution for a while now. However everything I have tried doesn't work or isn't permanent. I've changing resolution using xrandr. I've tried editing the X11 file. I've tried editing the lightdm configuration, but only get a black screen.

Currently I use a script every time I log in, but I would like my full resolution to be permanent. I would also like the other resolutions in between. Without running the script the maximum resolution I can get is 1024 x 768. I can get 1080 (not sure whether it is p or i). Please help me. Looking at a 4:3 boot screen, login screen and desktop on a 16:9 is very saddening :(.

If it helps I am using a Philips 234EL 1080p display coupled with Intel Sandy Bridge Graphics (2500 if I'm not mistaken)

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a kernel bug and it sounds as if you have a decent work around. Just run the script at log in. If you want a "fix" , identify the exact graphics card and file a bug report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `xrandr` commands run on startup.

Unfortunately, a lot of people have trouble making the commands permanent, so that they run on startup, but I'll show you how to do it the easy way:

- Create a bash script, `xrandr.sh` for example, and place your xrandr commands into it. It should look something like this

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  xrandr --newmode "1920x1200_60.00"  193.16  1920 2048 2256 2592  1200 1201 1204 1242  -HSync +Vsync
  xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1200_60.00
  xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1200_60.00
  ```
- Make the script executable with `chmod +x xrandr.sh`
- Search for "Startup Applications" in the dash, run it, and add the script as a startup application.

The commands will now run every time you log into your account.

**OR** you can go the easy way and use a program that does the above for you. I created [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/resolutionx/?source=navbar) program - which will work for you, since `xrandr` works with your setup.